# Pass MySQL query result to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to create tags in an input field with the help of JavaScript and try to suggest the user for auto-complete suggestions from the database.

I am being able to create tags with simple JavaScript but i am unable to fetch already created tags and pass it in JavaScript function for auto-complete suggestion.

**Input Field**

```
<input type="text" name="area_token" id="area_token">
```

**JavaScript Function**

```
$(function() {
    $("#area_token").tags({

    }).autofill({
        data:["java-script","MySQL","ajax","Python"]
    });
});
```

Here what I want is to pass to query the database and pass that to the data in that autofill function.

I have written a AJAX function to get the data from database

```
function display_detail_of_follow_up_meetings(studentid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        url: base_path+"admission_inquiry/display_inquiry_meetings_byinquiryid_json",
        data:({
            'inquiry_id':studentid
        }),
        beforeSend:function() {
            overlay_ajax();
        },
        success:function(data) {

        },
        error:function(){
            alert('ajax call failed...');
        }, 
        complete: function(){ 
            $.unblockUI();
        }            
    });  
}
```

What I am doing wrong here or how can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you please update your question with your `MySQL` query block and how you are trying to bind it to your `#area_token` field?

Comment: @DavidR i have added the function .

Comment: What is `.tags()`, and `.autofill()`, and `$.unblockUI()`?  This does not look like [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Answer (score 0):

If your function behind your AJAX request is OK, then you only need this "change"

```
function display_detail_of_follow_up_meetings(studentid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        url: base_path+"admission_inquiry/display_inquiry_meetings_byinquiryid_json",
        data:({
            'inquiry_id':studentid
        }),
        beforeSend:function() {
            overlay_ajax();
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // here is your MySQL result named "data"
            $("#area_token").tags({ }).autofill({
                data: data // and here you pass your data from AJAX
            });
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('ajax call failed...');
        }, 
        complete: function(){ 
            $.unblockUI();
        }            
    });  
}
```